# Console windows phone 8 with remote device

Tags: c#, debugging, console, windows-phone-8

maybe is a stupid question but I didn't find answers until now.
I'm developing with VSE2012 for Wp8 and use a device and not an emulator for develop (hyper-v has a conflict with virtualbox, so I've deactivated).
I've found a very annoying problem. It don't print to console output value that I use to debug. I've tried various configuration but nothing, and on msdn I've not found nothing...
So hope that someone of you can help me.

The question is simple: how can I print to console output window values ? 
Example: If I write:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("hello");
```

It doesn't  write nothing.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had the same problem, but I don't think you should use Console.WriteLine.

Try using Debug.WriteLine instead.

Comment: +1 `Debug.WriteLine` should work fine. Make sure you're running in debug mode.

Comment: You were right, I never thought of that (Thought to have been nearly an hour to find a solution)!
Thank you, thank you.
Debug.WriteLine work fine with debug mode!

Comment: In case you want to use this, like I did, make sure you include the following directive `using System.Diagnostics;` so you won't have to google the error... like I did :)